# Cleaning gps data csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, gps, lora

I am working on real time LoRa gps plotter in python. I get gps position  data from LoRa via serial and save them to a csv file. It is working, but I get the problem when i get corrupted gps data because of LoRa bad signal. Like so

```
45.830008,16.039911
45.830mdndn008,16.039911
45.830008,16.039oo9°1
45.830008,16.03991
45.830sj008,16.03#=991
```

What is the  way to read just the numeric data from csv file in python? I don't want to read the corrupted data. I just want to read integers. I am using pandas to read the csv file. like so

```
data = pd.read_csv(self.data_path, names=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], sep=',')


gps_data = tuple(zip(data['LATITUDE'].values, data['LONGITUDE'].values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want keep the numeric values you can do `to_numeric()` combined with `errors = 'coerce'`. Then invalid values will be set as `NaN`, see here [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
import pandas as pd

#read csv
data = pd.read_csv(self.data_path, names=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], sep=',')

# copy dataframe structure only, no data
gps_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)

# copy valid values only
gps_data['LATITUDE'] = pd.to_numeric(data['LATITUDE'], errors='coerce')
gps_data['LONGITUDE'] = pd.to_numeric(data['LONGITUDE'], errors='coerce')

print (data)
print (gps_data)

# drop rows with NaNs in lat OR long
gps_data = gps_data.dropna(subset=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']) # OR
#gps_data = gps_data.dropna(subset=['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], thresh=2) # AND threshold = 2
```

edit: you probably also want to drop the rows with empty `NaN` values